# How do you edit a control that add by code?

Tags: vb.net

What my problem is, I let User rename the picturebox. so my code like this :

> ```
>    Dim Picturebox As New PictureBox
>    Picturebox.Name = TextBox1.Text
> ```

And user can add another picturebox.

How can I make the picturebox drag able ?

I know to make picturebox drag able by MouseMove, MouseDown but how ?

like this ?

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles "Textbox1.text".MouseDown

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why would the user ever care or even know what your variables and controls are named?

Comment: I would suggest you read some [nice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973845.aspx) [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Answer (score 1):

The PictureBox does **not** need a name...

You'd use AddHandler to wire up the events to your handler, and then cast the "sender" parameter to get the source PB:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PB As New PictureBox
    AddHandler PB.MouseMove, AddressOf PB_MouseMove
    ' ... more code with "PB" ...
End Sub

Private Sub PB_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        PB.DoDragDrop("some data", DragDropEffects.All)
    End If
End Sub
```